# Using variable like function name in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help to fix the next issue :

```
functions_list = {
  0: "printHelp",
  1: "printVersion",
  2: "printList"
}

class StartUp():

  def printHelp():
    print("help function")

  def printVersion():
    print("version function")

  def printList():
    print("list function")

startUp.functions_list[0]()
```

How to execute this? Or what need to change to execute it?

My execute trace :

```
>>> StartUp.printHelp()
help function
>>> StartUp.functions_list[0]()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'StartUp' has no attribute 'functions_list'
```

Comment: Functions are first class object. You can refer to function by their name. You don't need to store their name as a string.

Comment: Call it by name. Why would you want the other way?

Comment: @Ausin This smells a bit like an XY problem, OP tries to achieve something else they don't tell us about (ie execute a method/function by its name they get from user input etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, all the methods miss the `self` argument. You need to include it or mark all method as static with the `staticmethod` decorator.

If you insist on using the string representation of the methods, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
functions_list = {
  0: "printHelp",
  1: "printVersion",
  2: "printList"
}

class StartUp:
  def printHelp(self):
    print("help function")

  def printVersion(self):
    print("version function")

  def printList(self):
    print("list function")

s = StartUp()
getattr(s, functions_list[0])()
```

Comment: Good use of `getattr`. +1 though why OP need this is still hidden.

Comment: Not real point in using strings with `getattr` calls. It's almost always much better to just handle functions straight up as objects in Python.

Comment: @ruohola "Not real point in using strings with getattr calls" This is exactly the use case for `getattr`. Again, we do not know what OP's real use case is. The fact the functions are first-class objects does not really help here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you'd want this, but here's a cleaned up and fixed version:

```
class StartUp():
    def printHelp():
        print("help function")

    def printVersion():
        print("version function")

    def printList():
        print("list function")

    functions_list = {
        0: printHelp,
        1: printVersion,
        2: printList
    }

StartUp.functions_list[0]()
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> help function
> ```

But Python is not Java, and there really isn't any point in having a class here. You should just define the functions and the dictionary (which you weirdly named `functions_list`) on the module level. I'm not even sure why you want to have the dictionary of the functions on the first place.

Comment: @DeepSpace This **does** work just fine. If you call the functions straight from the class name and not an instance, there's no need for `staticmethod` decorator. There's no point in fixing this more, since there's no point in doing this task this way.

Comment: I stand corrected, but still it is pretty much useless because as I mentioned, there will be no access to instance attributes. We can't assume that there are not any since OP may have stripped them away while preparing the MCVE

Comment: Note that the OP tries to invoke the methods by their **string** representation, not by a reference to them. This is a common problem that has several valid use cases

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes I noticed that. Most likely he's just creating a cli program that will take user input and run some functions based on that. For that (and almost always anyways) it's much better to just handle functions straight up as objects in Python. Not real point in using strings with `getattr` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any use of a class here, you can just define the functions first, create the dictionary you are doing, and then call from the dictionary

```
#Define functions here
def printHelp():
    print("help function")

def printVersion():
    print("version function")

def printList():
    print("list function")

#Define dictionary here
functions_list = {
  0: printHelp,
  1: printVersion,
  2: printList
}

#Call functions here
for item in functions_list.values():
    item()
```

Output will be

```
help function
version function
list function
```

And not sure why you are even doing that too, you can call functions directly by their name

```
#Define functions here
def printHelp():
    print("help function")

def printVersion():
    print("version function")

def printList():
    print("list function")

printHelp()
printVersion()
printList()
```

The output will be

```
help function
version function
list function
```

One extra tidbit is you can use a decorator `@staticmethod` for your methods you are calling directly using the class name

```
class StartUp:

    @staticmethod
    def printHelp():
        print("help function")

    @staticmethod
    def printVersion():
        print("version function")

    @staticmethod
    def printList():
        print("list function")

StartUp.printHelp()
StartUp.printVersion()
StartUp.printList()
```

The output will be

```
help function
version function
list function
```